# Get HTTPS site content using c++ QNetworkRequest

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, https, qnetworkrequest

I am trying to get the content of a site (json string) using Qt framework (QNetworkRequest) over VS2010 c++ environment. I have no problem reading data from HTTP site, however when I try to read the content of an HTTPS site I have no luck. On the other hand, the browser can "see" the site content. I think that it is a matter of certificates but I am not entirely sure. I have access only to ca.pem (that I exported) from firefox. I used dummy pem files for cert.pem and key.pem so that I don't leave the empty. Unfortunately I cannot get these files another way.

I get an error 99 code with the description "Private key does not certify public key, error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned". So it should be an error of the dummy key certificate.

However I cannot stop wondering how is it possible that the browser can "see" the content and through the code I can't? Is it possible to find a work around?

My code is the following:

```
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply *reply = NULL;

    QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();   
    config.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);  
    request.setSslConfiguration(config);
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://...."));
    addSSl(&request);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ServerHeader, "application/json");

    reply = manager->get(request);  

    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,   SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void addSSL(QNetworkRequest *request)
{   
    QString cacert_path="../certificates/cacert.pem";
    QString cert_path="../certificates/cert.pem";
    QString key_path="../certificates/key.pem";

    QFile cacert_file(cacert_path); 

    QSslConfiguration SslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());

    QList<QSslCertificate> caList = SslConfiguration.caCertificates();
    QSslCertificate cacert_cert=QSslCertificate::fromPath(cacert_path,QSsl::Pem)[0];

    QSslCertificate cert_cert=QSslCertificate::fromPath(cert_path,QSsl::Pem)[0];

    caList.append(cacert_cert);
    SslConfiguration.setCaCertificates(caList);
    SslConfiguration.setLocalCertificate(cert_cert);
    SslConfiguration.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);

    QFile key_file(key_path);
    bool exists=key_file.exists();
    QDir d = QFileInfo(key_file).absoluteDir();    
    QString absolutepath=d.absolutePath();

    QDir myDir("certificates");
    QStringList filesList = myDir.entryList(QDir::Files);

    key_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
    QSslKey sslkey(&key_file,QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, QSsl::PrivateKey);   
    key_file.close();

    SslConfiguration.setPrivateKey(sslkey);
    request->setSslConfiguration(SslConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: No error reported in replyFinished()? (check reply->error() and reply->errorString())

Comment: I get an error 99 code with the description "Private key does not certify public key, error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned". So it should be an error of the dummy key certificate.

Answer (score -1):

Please copy these .DLLs to your Application Folder:

`libeay32.dll`
`ssleay32.dll`

QT needs these to Work with SSL.